# Making an animation with a transparent background blender cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, export, video

I am currently trying to export a animation with a transparent background to lay over the beginning of my YouTube videos. I got this idea from the famous YouTuber captainSparklez. I have tried changing the output to RGBA but that does not work and I have also tried selecting transparent in the film section but that doesn't work either. keep in mind I am using Cycles to do this and I don't know if u can render a QuickTime animation in cycles. I will be using this in my editor Adobe Primer Pro if you need to know that. My version of blender I am using is Blender 2.78a If you could help that would be amazing thank you for your time.

Comment: In the render settings under "Film" make sure "Transparent" is checked off.

Comment: Blender supports no video format with alpha. Use an image Sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Just render it out as a PNG sequence (with alpha) then take those files into Premiere as a sequence.

1. In your render settings tab, make sure your dimensions/frame rate are correct.
2. in the output dropdown make sure you set a destination place, and make sure PNG is selected with alpha
3. Make sure you hit animation and NOT render when you are ready to render out all your frames.

[image]

In Premiere make sure you click "image sequence" when bringing in your files.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but I have 360 images and can not find a video that clearly states how to do what you said. How do I export them out of blender as a PNG sequence.

Comment: and as Dontwalk stated, In the render settings under "Film" make sure "Transparent" is checked off.

Comment: Alright I figured it out thank you very much and hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: if it was helpful please mark it as answered.